# Start iOS app with a bluetooth device

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I'm trying to make an app that is initiated through a bluetooth device 4.0 
Apple allows a similar thing?

I'm struggling to even find a starting point. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"Start iOS app with a Bluethooth device"` - this can't be done the app will need to have been started first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Popeye has mentioned in his comment, it's not possible within the confines of the iOS SDK/App store policies to programmatically execute code or launch an application on iOS via bluetooth.